# Send full object using POST in angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, web-services, post

I have this webservice:

```
@POST
@Path("/addObj")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public static void addObj(@FormParam("obj1") final Obj1 obj1, 
            @FormParam("obj2") final Obj2 obj2) {
    ...
}
```

And I want to use it in:

```
    $scope.addObj1= function (obj1, obj2) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "mobile/addObj",
        data: $.param({
           obj1: obj1, //or even: "obj1": obj1
           obj2: obj2 //or even: "obj2": obj2
        }),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    }).then(
            function(response){
                ...
            }, function(error) {...});  
};
```

Obj1 is like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Obj1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Obj1 implements Serializable{
    private field1;
    private List<Obj2> listObj2;
    ...
}
```

I really can't figure out how to use it. (both objects are null in the addObj java function)

Is it possible to send an entire Object (obj1 and obj2) using this post ws ?

I tryed using different ways to write it, different MediaType, ContentType...

Thanks for your help.

For info:

Forma Data:

article%5Bcode%5D=VA0004&article%5Bnom%5D=LOCATION+IPAD&article%5Bprix%5D=7.5&article%5Bstock%5D=0&article%5B%24%24hashKey%5D=00O

Article = Obj1

```
class Artcile () {String code, String nom, Double prix, Double stock}
```

Request Headers:

> POST /espace-conciergerie-front/mobile/addObj HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: localhost:8080
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 129
>
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Referer: http://localhost:8080/espace-conciergerie-front/monEspace.action
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=1D98F69A79EEB041391D374E066688CE

Comment: And how does body of your request method look like?

Comment: This is the form data: article%5Bcode%5D=VA0004&article%5Bnom%5D=LOCATION+IPAD&article%5Bprix%5D=7.5&article%5Bstock%5D=0&article%5B%24%24hashKey%5D=00O